# Delete backgound for ID with conditional if statement

Tags: conditional-tags

how can I delete a background for #main only on my posts. I know that I have to create a conditional `if` statement in my functions.php file with `if (is_post())` but I'm just not sure how to write it.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

i am guessing you want a different style for the div#main for pages and a different style for posts right ?

Comment: correct. I need a background of none or transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the classes offered by your body_class() function to your `<body>` element. Then overwrite your div with the ID `#main` on your posts page with a [higher specifity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and set this div to `display: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Chris here is how i propose you do it;

## markup (HTML / PHP)

```
<div id="main" class="<?php if(is_single($post)) { echo 'post'; } else { echo 'page'; }; ?>">
```

## css

```
#main .post
{
    background:none;
}
#main .page
{
    background:#CCC;
}
```

Basically the code checks to see if the post is a "single post" and if true it returns the class="post" if not it returns the class="page";

Add the markup to the place you are trying to put this into effect i.e. your template file.

This should do what you want it to do :)

Comment: If the class and ID apply to the same element they shouldn't have a space between them, eg. `#main.post`..